# appium .clear() doesnt work on EditText java

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, appium

When I'm executing .clear() method on Appium on an EditText instead of clearing it the cursor goes on the beginning of the EditText and it shows a suggestion to replace the first word. Here is the java code that I'm using:

```
List<WebElement> clearName = driver.findElements(By.className("android.widget.EditText"));        
    clearName.get(0).clear();
```

Same thing happens when i try to clear the text by name:

```
driver.findElement(By.name("My Name")).clear();
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: For anyone else coming across this, I'm using Appium 1.4.16.1 and experiencing an issue where sending text sometimes adds back in the original value. In this case, manually calling .clear() before sending the text appeared to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

In latest version of Appium, we just need to call `sendKey()` that internally clears the field value and updates with value that you have passed.

Can you please try this?

```
driver.findElement(By.name("My Name")).sendKey("some text");
```

Comment: Instead of clearing the field value, the new value that I pass is added on the beginning. For example if I first had a value in my field: "My Name" and then I send "His Name " after running both of them I get:"His Name My Name"

Comment: Okay. Which version of Appium you are using? And I hope you are using Appium-java cliet library (not Selenium standalone server)?

Comment: I'm using version 1.2.4.1 because I figured out that there is an issue with the newest version with devices running 4.2.2. findElement wasn't working! And yes I'm using java-client 1.7.0. With all the newest jars I was getting and error on command: driver = new AppiumDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities) ;

Comment: Yes; In newer version findelemtnt throws exception if locator matches more than one element. You can try other finding element approaches. Like selecting based on index or using findelement"s" & then retrieving 1st element or findElementsByAndroidUIAutomator etc.. I would suggest newer version of the appium as it has got lot of improvements...